# NFC Card Emulation Mode and Peer to peer

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, hce

I want to build Android apps that can be used for a student attandance tracking system. Student's phone will acts as an ID (just push data) and teacher's phone will acts as reader (pull data). So my questions are:

1. I know that a phone with Android 4.4 can use HCE but can an Android phone act as reader for that HCE emulated card?
2. If it can, then which mode is better? HCE or peer-to-peer mode? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?
3. Are there any tutorials on this?

thx before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to with one touch two android devices exchange data via NFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815555/is-it-possible-to-with-one-touch-two-android-devices-exchange-data-via-nfc)

Answer (score 3):

1. Android phones can either act as HCE or as a Card reader, depending on the app.
2. The students should use the HCE and the teacher should use the Card reader mode
3. With these samples you can make your teacher app and the student app. 
   http://developer.android.com/samples/CardEmulation/index.html
   http://developer.android.com/samples/CardReader/index.html

Comment: thx mate, but can i build card reader mode app that read the HCE in ICS?

Comment: Yes but only if you disable Beam. Beam is the default 'mode' of NFC for all Android devices. Only in KitKat (Android 4.4) there is an option to temporarily disable this mode in-app.