# Is HCE bi-directional communication possible?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815555/is-it-possible-to-with-one-touch-two-android-devices-exchange-data-via-nfc), by using the sample app for [card emulation](http://developer.android.com/samples/CardEmulation/index.html) and [card reader](http://developer.android.com/samples/CardReader/index.html):

1. we can setup a HCE card (card emulation) in "Device A", and send the
   data to a reader (card reader) in "Device B".
2. What if I want to continue this process by sending a "amount" from
   "Device B" back to "Device A"? Is this achievable?

Note: Both devices are 4.4+.

Answer (score 1):

[HCE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) use [ISO-7816-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7816#7816-4:_Organization.2C_security_and_commands_for_interchange) standard so you communicate with [APDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit)

APDU process is:
Reader send command (with optional data) to card.
Card respond (with optional data) to reader.

Card could not send command to Reader.