# Can NFC using android beam send and receive in the same beam?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I want to be able to send and receive information in a single touch.

I followed this tutorial to on using NFC to send info: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/04/communication-between-android-using-nfc.html

It works great but I am only able to send information from one phone at a time.  So if I want to say transfer phone numbers by touching phones it has to be done twice, once to send from phone A to phone B and once to send from phone B to phone A.  Is it possible to reduce this to a single touch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to with one touch two Android devices exchange data via NFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23815555/2425802)

Answer (score 0):

There is one way that I know which can achieve this.

For android device 4.4 and after. You can use NfcAdapter to restrict an android device to Reader Mode. Once touch another device which has set with HCE tag, you can transceive data and get a respond data. it's a bidirectional communication.

For more information, you can check this.

http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/25/android-p2p-nfc

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html

and here is my project to share wifi hotspot with NFC touch

https://github.com/Youxian-Chen/WiFiShare

Hope this help! if any question, please let me know.